# Mongo db not in query by having two subset of documents from same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb. Assume the following. There are 3 types of documents in one collection x, y and z.

```
docs = [{
  "item_id": 1
  "type": "x"
},
{
  "item_id": 2
  "type": "x"
},{
  "item_id": 3
  "type": "y",
  "relavent_item_ids": [1, 2]
},
{
  "item_id": 3
  "type": "y",
  "relavent_item_ids": [1, 2, 3]
},{
  "item_id": 4
  "type": "z",     
}]
```

I want to get the following.

- Ignore the documents with type `z`
- Get all the documents of type `x` where it's `item_id` is not in `relavent_item_ids` of type `y` documents.
- The result should have `item_id` field.

I tried doing `match` `$in` but this returns me all the records, I am unable to figure out how to have in condition with subset of documents of type `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $facet: {
          firstQuery: [
              { 
                  $match: { type: { $eq: "x", $ne: "z" } } 
              },
              { 
                  $project: { 
                      item_id : 1, _id: 0 
                  } 
              }
          ],
          secondQuery: [
              { 
                  $match: { type: "y" } 
              },
              { 
                  $group: { 
                      _id: null, 
                      relavent: { $push: "$relavent_item_ids" } 
                  } 
              },
              { 
                  $project: { 
                      relavent: { 
                          $reduce: { 
                               input: "$relavent",
                               initialValue:  [ ],
                               in: { $setUnion: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { secondQuery: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$secondQuery", 0 ] } }
  },
  { 
      $project: { 
          result: {
              $filter: { 
                   input: "$firstQuery" ,
                   as: "e",
                   cond: { $not: [ { $in: [ "$$e.item_id", "$secondQuery.relavent" ] } ] }
              }
          }
      } 
  },
] )
```

Using the input documents in the question post and adding one more following document to the collection:

```
{
  "item_id": 11,
  "type": "x",     
}
```

: only this document's `item_id` (value `11`) will show in the output.

The aggregation uses a `$facet` to make two individual queries with a single pass. The first query gets all the "x" types (and ignores type "z") as an array. The second query gets an array of `relavent_item_ids` with unique values (from the documents of type "y"). The final, `$project` stage filters the first query result array with the condition:

> Get all the documents of type x where it's item_id is not in
>   relavent_item_ids of type y documents

Comment: Thanks @parasd_, It works great. Facets are easy to understand. I get that you are running two queries and then doing operation on them. Using `addFields` you are adding a field to all the documents of firstQuery which are list of relaventIds correct?

Comment: Technically `$ne: "z"` is not required. I checked it.

Comment: _Using addFields you are adding a field to all the documents of firstQuery which are list of relaventIds correct?_  Yes, and then used for comparison. The result of each facet is an array. We don't want an array of arrays (for the relavent_item_ids); so I just get the array element as a document from the _secondQuery_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query

```
const item_ids = (await db.collection.find({ "type": "y" })).map(({ relavent_item_ids }) => relavent_item_ids)

const result = db.collection.find({
  "item_id": { "$exists": true },
  "type": { "$ne": "z", "$eq": "x" },
  "relavent_item_ids": { "$nin": item_ids }
})

console.log({ result })
```

*Ignore the documents with type z* --> Use [**`$ne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) not equal to query operator to filter out `z` types.

*Get all the documents of type x where it's item_id is not in relavent_item_ids of type y documents* --> Use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to match the same documents fields.

*The result should have item_id field* --> Use [**`$exists`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its an elegant solution.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {   
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$relavent_item_ids",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        } 
    },
    {   
        "$group": {
            "_id":null, 
            "relavent_item_ids": {"$addToSet":"$relavent_item_ids"},
            "other_ids": {
                "$addToSet":{
                    "$cond":[
                        {"$eq":["$type", "x"]},
                        "$item_id",
                        null
                    ]
                }
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$project":{ 
                "includeIds": {"$setDifference":["$other_ids", "$relavent_item_ids"]}
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$includeIds"
    },
    {
        "$match": {"includeIds":{"$ne":null}}
    },
    {
        "$lookup":{
                "from": "test",
                "let": { "includeIds": "$includeIds"},
                "pipeline": [
                      { "$match":
                         { "$expr":
                            { "$and":
                               [
                                 { "$eq": [ "$item_id",  "$$includeIds" ] },
                                 { "$eq": [ "$type", "x" ] }
                               ]
                            }
                         }
                      }
                ],
                "as": "result"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$result"
    },
])
```